# Seed fake images in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova, faker

I'm trying to generate a fake image to populate seeder data.

I created a seeder with this:

```php
$this->faker->image(storage_path('app/public/products'), 500, 500)
```

When I try to access them through Laravel Nova to see them, I get this kind of URL: `http://localhost/storage/var/www/html/storage/app/public/products/c8831002794cc55fe046c5e2b65794d4.png`

In the DB it's saved as: `/var/www/html/storage/app/public/products/c8831002794cc55fe046c5e2b65794d4.png`

Any idea what I've done wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I want to add in database table just name of image, NOT a whole path of image and I want to do with Factory and Seeds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56292415/i-want-to-add-in-database-table-just-name-of-image-not-a-whole-path-of-image-an)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [method signature](https://fakerphp.github.io/formatters/image/#image_1) for `image()`:

```
function image(
    ?string $dir = null,
    int $width = 640,
    int $height = 480,
    ?string $category = null,
    bool $fullPath = true,
    bool $randomize = true,
    ?string $word = null,
    bool $gray = false,
    string $format = 'png'
)
```

Setting `$fullPath` to `false` will fix your issue:

```
$this->faker->image(storage_path('app/public/products'), 500, 500, null, false)
```

Comment: Now it's returning http://localhost/storage/3bf64f4fc195f024288ea2cf282513e5.png

And in the database there's only the filename 3bf64f4fc195f024288ea2cf282513e5.png

Maybe I'm missing something in Nova... i'll go re-read this doc.

Comment: So yeah, my code follow the doc, the problem is that in the database it's not storing the path "after" the disk path, for instance here the products/ part should be in the db. I can prepend it to the faker results, but is there a more "standard" way of doing it ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$this->faker->image('app/public/products',400,300, null, false)
```

if you have a view then:

```
<img src="/my/path/{{ $item->image}}" >
```